# Should I install the proprietary CPU drivers?

Tags: release-loki, drivers, intel, cpu

Should I enable the proprietary CPU drivers displayed under 'Software & updates - Additional drivers'?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling this wouldn't harm your machine. Users of CPUs belonging to the Intel Haswell and Broadwell processor families in particular must install these microcode updates to ensure system stability. But all Intel users should install the updates as a matter of course.